# How to set listener for bitmaps in a canvas in my custom view...?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a custom view in which i am drawing many bitmaps,

Now i want to change image bitmap when user clicks on it.

How to do this...?

here is my onDraw method of custom view.

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Bitmap mBitmap = null;

        int x = row * 20;
        int y = clm * 20;
        System.out.println("the x=" + x + "y=" + y);
        int counter = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a <= x; a += 20)
            for (int b = 0; b <= y; b += 20) {
                mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.test);
                canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, a, b, null);
                counter++;
            }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make more than one bitmap clickable, you are going to need to use a ViewGroup class as OnClickListener is implemented to the view.

UPDATE

You do realize views go inside layouts. when you see 5 buttons on a screen, they are 5 views inside Layout(ViewGroup). The listeners you add are on the views. If you got multiple bitmaps you want to click, you need to make the as imageviews and add them to the layout. If you want to layout them in a particular order you need to create a custom viewgroup. With a custom view, you can only set click to the whole view and not parts of the view. Maybe you can overide a view onTouch event and capture the x,y cordinates of the touch and find which part clicked by a lot of calculations. But thats a big hack and view group is the natural way of doing things.

Comment: You need to put your bitmaps into imageviews and then put the imageviews into the layout(ViewGroup). The listeners are then set on the imageviews

Comment: my custom view dont have any layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
View.SetOnClickListner()
```

works for any View, just replace View with your customView here. you get access to the view on  which the click occurred. then you can change the bitmap of the view.

Comment: It works on whole custom view but my custom view has many bitmaps... I want to listener on each and every bitmap.